# Compilation issues between servers

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using the following Makefile to compile and run a c program on my local machine

```
# project name 
TARGET   = server

CC       = gcc
# compiling flags 
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall -I. -g


LINKER   = gcc -o
# linking flags 
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm


SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONEY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

This works perfectly on my local environment which is a mac(though there's nothing in the code that's mac specific).

However when I compile this code on a linux server I get the following error.

```
Build failed. Wrong Architecture.
```

When I manually compile the source files on this server running gcc file1 file2.... It compiles fine. What am I doing wrong with my Makefile.

Comment: The "Wrong architecture" message indicates that you have copied some library or object file, or even executable, from your own development system to the other system.

Comment: There are no "Build failed. Wrong Architecture." strings in your Makefile. This message is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Also, to help with debugging the makefile, remove the ampersands so you see the actual commands and their arguments that `make` runs. That will help you locate which command causes the error.

Comment: LFLAGS   specifies a library.  Have you checked that library?  The `file` command can tell you something about it, IIRC.

Comment: Inasmuch as @JoachimPileborg is very likely right, simply performing a `make clean` might be enough to resolve your problem.  If it isn't, then the build environment on your Linux server is probably broken.

Comment: Note also: although the `.PHONY` target has special meaning to some `make`s, I am not aware of any that attribute the same (or any) significance to `.PHONEY`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make clean before you make? I think there are some files or libraries were built on other architecture

Comment: Although this may constitute useful advice, it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure that the makefile is the problem and this answer may very well be the right way to address the problem.